# How to get the day name in ios

Tags: ios7.1, nscalendar

I want to get the name of the day. As an example

If I have a day like `01/08/2014` I want to find 1st is which day Monday,tuesday.....or saturday likewise. How can I do it in iOS. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];
```

More info within [apples date formatting guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i)